# Reducing paginated query

Tags: scala

I have a function such as:

```
def getPage(page: Int): List[Object]
```

and I would like to call this function, while reducing the result into one set which contains all the pages.

Something like this:

```
val allPages = getPage(page++).takeWhile(nonEmpty).reduce(_ ::: _)
```

how could I achieve this?

Comment: `Stream.from(0).map(getPage) ...` etc.

Comment: I don't think this question is descriptive enough. It is better if you improve the question by specifying the input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reducing a structure, you are creating one, this functionality is called `unfold`. Unfortunately `unfold` isn't in the std lib, but it is easy enough to write and include yourself.

A simple unfold fn looks like:

```
def unfoldRight[A, B](seed: B)(f: B => Option[(A, B)]): Stream[A] =
  f(seed) match {
    case Some((a, b)) => a #:: unfoldRight(b)(f)
    case None => Stream.empty[A]
  }
```

You would use it like so:

```
unfoldRight(0) { i =>
  val page = getPage(i)
  if (page.isEmpty) None
  else Some((page, i + 1))
}
```

Being that this is a trivial unfold which just increments a value, the `from` method on the `Stream` and `Iterator` api will do fine (thanks @Dima)

```
Iterator.from(0).map(getPage).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
```

Comment: That's great. Followup question. Is there a way to do something similar but instead return a iterator, in case I don't want to load all the pages into memory at once?

Comment: `Stream` is a lazy structure, so it won't be in memory all at once. You can convert a `Stream -> Iterator` by calling `.iterator` on the `Stream`.

Comment: Even after you have iterated over the entire stream, so you evaluate each of the lazy loaded functions, wouldn't all the pages then be in memory? Is this avoided by using converting it to an iterator?

Comment: Sure, it is in standard library. Just do `Iterator.from(0).map(getPage).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)` - that's your unfold